# Why the rotation using the Coroutine is rotating but the object is in slant ? and how to rotate it with Coroutine non stop?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 targetRotation;
    public float duration;
    public bool spinInUpdate = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (spinInUpdate == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(LerpFunction(Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), duration));
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (spinInUpdate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LerpFunction(Quaternion endValue, float duration)
    {
        float time = 0;
        Quaternion startValue = transform.rotation;

        while (time < duration)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startValue, endValue, time / duration);
            time += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.rotation = endValue;
    }
}
```

slant I mean this is how it's rotating with the Coroutine the small cube that rotate is in slant :

[image: slant]

When using the Update way it's rotating fine and this is how it should rotating also with the Coroutine for example on the X only :

[image: Cube]

The small cube when rotating either in update or in the Coroutine  should not be slant. but it's slant in the Coroutine.

And how can I add a speed factor to the Update to control the rotation in the Update in case using the Update ?

About controlling the speed in the Update I just added a global float variable and in the Update :

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0));
```

and it's working for the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coroutine is adjusting the world rotation, not the local rotation. Try using local cords.

If this is not the case you might need to include more information about what you are trying to accomplish, and what is going wrong. As is it’s a little unclear.